# JavaFX - How to load a specific AnchorPane's contents from an FXML file?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to make an application which switches between scenes back and forth however I need to load a specific AnchorPane's contents into another AnchorPane when the scene switches back. For Example:

In my FXML1, I have a hierarchy that looks like this:

AnchorPane0

----SplitPane

--------AnchorPane1

--------AnchorPane2

In FXML2 the hierarchy is just this:

AnchorPane0

So I load FXML1, then I have a button that switches scenes loading FXML2.AnchorPane0 into FXML1.AnchorPane2. I have a back button in FXML2.AnchorPane0 that needs to load the original scene of FXML1.AnchorPane2 into FXML1.AnchorPane2. Right now my back button loads all 4 containers of FXML1 into FXML1.AnchorPane2. So my questions is, how do I load a specific container's contents preferably without making FXML1.AnchorPane2 its own FXML? Do I need to write a get method for the FXML1.AnchorPane2 to access its contents or is there a way to return an AnchorPane with all of its contents in place already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as shown below:

```
AnchorPane loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("myFXML.fxml"));

SplitPane spane = (SplitPane) loader.getChildren().get(0);

AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) spane.getItems().get(1);

foregroundAnchorPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
```